# Why script send /n?

Tags: php, frameworks, kohana

The source -

Controller -

```
Model::factory('index')->send_comment(mysql_real_escape_string($name), mysql_real_escape_string($artcl_id), mysql_real_escape_string($text), mysql_real_escape_string(time()), mysql_real_escape_string($ip));
                        Model::factory('index')->update_comment_count($artcl_id);
```

Before that $_POST data was checked with trim() function and $text is trim($_POST['text']).

But when I write a comment -

```
Hello!

This is a comment!
```

To database script sends

```
Hello!/n/nThis is a comment!
```

In view -

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars(nl2br($comment['text'])); ?>
```

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Col. Shrapnel is right and you use the Database module (ORM uses it, just saying) you do not have to spend energy to escape input yourself. You will however have to spend enery if you want to send unescaped input to the database.

See [Database::quote()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Database#quote), [Database::quote_column()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Database#quote_column), [Database::quote_identifier()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Database#quote_identifier) and [Database::quote_table()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Database#quote_table) which are used throughout the database module.

PS. ALWAYS validate input.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that it sends `Hello!\n\nThis is a comment!` and there are no mistake.
Everything is okay